# Need recommendation in adf pipeline source properties while loading delimited text files from azure blob to snowflake

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image] We are trying to load a delimited file which has blank data for few columns located in azure blob and would like to get a value like NA in our target snowflake table whenever we encounter a blank value in source csv file. We have been trying to provide a NA against the Null option but it is not working, any suggestions?

Here is the screenshot of what i have mentioned above.

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used data flow activity in Azure data factory to resolve this issue.

Source file with `NULL` value in `“Name”` column.

[image]

Now use Derived Column transformation. In Derived column's settings Select column name and use `iifNull({Name}, 'NA')` expression.

[image]

In data preview, `Null` value in Name column is replaced with `NA`.

[image]

You can follow the above steps to replace Null values and Sink data from blob storage to Snowflake.